# Calling a Scala from Java Play Framework which takes a ClassTag

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am trying to make a call from a Play Java class to a Scala method which takes a ClassTag as a parameter

My failing attempt is

```
 Option<LocalUser> localUser = Cache.getAs(userId.userId(), app, new ClassTag<LocalUser>() );
```

The API method looks like this

```
Cache.getAs(String key, Application app, ClassTag<LocalUser> ct );
```

Comment: What do you mean by failing?

Comment: it says cant instantiate ClassTag as its abstract..

Comment: Hmm. It should work. Which ClassTag do you import? From which package?

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue when calling a different Scala API from Java.  You'd use:

```
ClassTag<LocalUser> tag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(LocalUser.class);
```

I'm not sure why Scala requires another class and a static object, but I think this is essentially the equivalent of a static method `ClassTag.apply(Class)`.

Comment: You don't need `MODULE$`, you can just write `scala.reflect.ClassTag.apply(LocalUser.class);`

Comment: Or just `ClassTag(LocalUser.class)`