# Making a Graph in Spark GraphX using Java bindings: What are those "evidence" arguments?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-graphx

In the [Spark GraphX javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/graphx/Graph.html) the `fromEdges()` method has undocumented arguments like `evidence$17`.  Presumably these are artifacts of the Scala implementation, but what should I do with them in Java?

```
public static <VD,ED> Graph<VD,ED> fromEdges(RDD<Edge<ED>> edges,
     VD defaultValue,
     StorageLevel edgeStorageLevel,
     StorageLevel vertexStorageLevel,
     scala.reflect.ClassTag<VD> evidence$16,
     scala.reflect.ClassTag<ED> evidence$17)
```

UPDATE: found some other Scala/Java examples, and it *seems* like the right thing is `ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(myClass)` where `myClass` is the class of the VD or ED type, respectively. Not that this actually works, as it leads to later, mysterious exceptions, like `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer` deep in `org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartitionBuilder.toEdgePartition`

UPDATE: Indeed, the ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Long.class) works for me.  The error I was getting was due to passing in 1 for the default value instead of 1L.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? I would expect the scala.reflect.ClassTag.apply(YourVertex.class) and scala.reflect.ClassTag.apply(YourEdge.class) expressions to work as the evidence arguments. The [Calling a Scala from Java Play Framework which takes a ClassTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582045/calling-a-scala-from-java-play-framework-which-takes-a-classtag) thread seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks Leonid.  Sorry I forgot to follow up, see my latest update.  This is solved, except that I'm getting a StackOverflow error from GraphX, but I'll start a new post for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evidence arguments are filled in using ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(myClass) where myClass is the class of the VD or ED type, respectively.

If you use Long.class for the ED and VD types, make sure to use a matching value for the defaults when you call `Graph.fromEdges()`.  In particular for Long.class use e.g. `1L` for the default value instead of `1`.